# How to access capsule info in Javascript?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

How can I access capsule-specific information in Javascript code?

I want to include my capsule id and version in a User-Agent when communicating with my backend. Ideally I would also be able to get the Bixby version and Android version my capsule is running on. I'm hoping there's something like `$vivContext` which I can just hand over to my Javascript code.

Comment: You may want to suggest this as a Feature Request to the Bixby team https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `$vivContext` does NOT hold capsule id or version. There is also no build-in for fetching content of capsule.bxb yet.

However, you can use [config API](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/capsule-config).

After defining `capusleID` and `version` property of your capsule in term & capsules section in developer center, you can use the following code in your JS file.

```
var config = require('config');
var myID = config.get('capsuleID');
var myVersion = config.get('version');
```